# Why "operator<" for std::vector<int>::iterator seems to compare absolute values when out of range (before .begin())?

Tags: c++

[cppreference on std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) doesn't seem to have any links for `std::vector<T>::iterator` type. Since it is a bidirectional iterator on a contigious memory, I supposed that it can be "negative".
`std::distance(vec.begin(), std::prev(vec.begin())` yields `-1`, and I ended up using `std::distance` to compare iterators for a loop.
But I was expecting `while(iterLeft < iterRight)` to be a valid check, and it is shorter than `while(std::distance(iterLeft, iterRight) > 0)`.

This code, however, demonstrates that `operator<` for some reason seems to compare absolute values:
**(This code surved to recreate the problem. The actual code had a variable-sized vector as an input)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{};
    auto iterLeft = vec.begin(),
        iterRight = std::prev(vec.end());

    std::cout << "Left = " << std::distance(vec.begin(), iterLeft) 
        << ", Right = " << std::distance(vec.begin(), iterRight) 
        << ", Left < Right: " << std::boolalpha << bool(iterLeft < iterRight)
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Program returned: 0
> Left = 0, Right = -1, Left < Right: true

https://godbolt.org/z/PErY35Ynj

---

So basically the UB is caused **Not** by `std::prev(vec.end())`, but by an iterator goind out of range (before `.begin()`).

---

The code example is just to recreate the problem.
Initially the code is to traverse an array with 2 iterators and the intent was to make the code declarative (meaning to handle empty arrays  without an explicit check).

```
for (auto leftIter = vec.begin(), rightIter = std::prev(vec.end()); leftIter < rightIter;)
{
 // do stuff
 ++leftIter;
 --rightIter;
}
```

The code worked fine for most cases, but empty arrays. Hence the question.

Comment: Works when both are actually valid iterators: https://godbolt.org/z/88xG7zffq

Comment: `std::prev(vec.end())` has undefined behavior. `vec.end()` is also `vec.begin()` since your vector is empty. Decrementing the iterator to the beginning causes undefined behavior. You can calculate the distance between valid iterators also to negative values, but you cannot decrement iterators to "negative indices" in the range.

Comment: @user4581301 since `c+11` it can be negative https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: I was trying to make a joke about how `std::vector` was not a physics vector, but I think I need to workshop that one a bit more.

Comment: Distance from `std::begin` to another iterator can never be less than zero, the fact that you get -1 should be clear evidence that you have Undefined Behavior. Your mistake was trying to get different iterators on an empty range. Try adding elements to the vector before calculating iterators. https://godbolt.org/z/84YfbMcxr

Comment: As for the posted question "Why X compares absolute values?" there is [no indication](https://godbolt.org/z/5e1E5Y7dG) that absolute values are being compared.  I presume that detail from the question is a _guess_ at what is happening.

Comment: @DrewDormann I've updated the title.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have updated the question. I didn't try an *empty range*. For a variable-rabased range this code worked unless the length was 0. I didn't want to explicitly check for that condition, and have the loop handle that case. That is out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::distance` can yield negative values if applied to valid iterators to the same range and `operator<` can be used to compare the ordering of valid iterators into the same range. And it does this comparison in the expected way. `iterLeft < iterRight` will be equivalent to `std::distance(iterLeft, iterRight) > 0`.

However the only valid iterators are those in the range from `begin()` to `end()`. Trying to obtain an iterator "before" `begin()` or "after" `end()` causes undefined behavior.

So `std::distance(vec.begin(), std::prev(vec.begin())` does not result in `-1`. It has undefined behavior.

Similarly in your code block `std::prev(vec.end())` has undefined behavior because the vector is empty and so `vec.begin() == vec.end()`.